# Unity3d Android app does not install properly when application binary is split

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

The app runs fine in the editor, but when I run it on a device I get two errors:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException : assets/build_info.txt

and then a error from my loading method that says the scene main_menu could not be loaded because its not in the build settings(it is);

What is this build_info.txt that I have never heard of before and why did it suddenly go missing after I imported the google OBB downloader plugin?

UPDATE : The problem seems to be connected to the split application binary option, since without it the app builds fine. Problem is I have to use it since its bigger than 50 mb.

UPDATE 2 : The problem magically fixes itslef after the device is restarted. This happens on multiple devices, even if the game is downloaded from the google play store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason removing the `maxSdkVersion` attribute from the  `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>` tag in the manifest solved the issue.

Answer (score -1):

this might help

maybe you didn't add the scene into the build settings . thats why current scene is running on the editor but the build game is not running !

goto file-> buildSettings -> add the scene on the top box

or click the add current button.

the scene at 0 position will be loaded first !

Comment: I did say in my question that it is added in the build settings. For some reason unity is not creating this build_info.txt that holds the scene order.